# Simple NMAKE file fails (1 echo command)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, makefile, nmake

I can't, for the life of me, figure out what I've done to my build environment.  Even now, the simplest of make files fails me:

win32.mak:

```
ALL:
    echo test
```

command:

```
nmake -f win32.mak
```

output:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.51106.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        echo Hey!
The system cannot find the path specified.
Hey!
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'echo' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

---

Something that may be related (or not):  Whenever I open up the Developer Command Prompt for VS2012, I'm greeted with two lines of "The system cannot find the path specified."  This is relatively new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who knew the problem would be related to Ansicon:

I found the answer to my problem [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637922/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-when-starting-ruby-and-rails-command-p)

I fixed it be uninstalling ansicon and reinstalling it from a more permanent location on disk.