# node.js npm error message - system cannot find the path specified

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a strange error message I don't understand or can't get rid of.
Secondly when I try to create express app on webstorm it can't find express.
I'm using windows 7 64 bit.

PS `C:\dv> npm -v`

The system cannot find the path specified.

```
1.2.14
```

PS `C:\dv>`

many thanks in advance

Jeremy

Answer (score 13):

It's a really old post, but I thought I'd share just in case it helps someone. In my case, the issue wasn't with npm, but instead with ansicon.

Removing the value of the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` resolved the issue, as described in these links...

https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/121

[The system cannot find the path specified when starting Ruby and Rails command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637922/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-when-starting-ruby-and-rails-command-p)

Comment: Thanks a lot, uninstalling/reinstalling did nothing but this worked for me as well (Windows10) !!!

Comment: Thank you so much! I had installed ConEmu and had later uninstalled it, which was throwing the '..cannot find path..' error. Deleting that fixed it!

Comment: Answer fixed my issue as well 8/14/2017. No clue where, why or how `ansicon` ended up installed on my machine.

Comment: Thanks, similar to others I had once had ConEmu installed.   I was having lots of problems with getting npm to run, and removing this registry key was the answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I tried to install clink as command line and followed some steps for installation, this caused the problem. Just removed autorun and it works.

Comment: For me, it was having Anaconda3 installed and then uninstalled. This set the Autorun key but didn't clean it up.

Answer (score 12):

For me , Deleting these two folder worked:

JUST Delete

```
C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

AND

```
C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

Answer (score 4):

I spent days figuring out how to fix this. Finally, using **Process Monitor** program, I found out:

1. npm was trying to access a file in `%APPDATA%/Temp` which no longer existed since I had uninstalled that program.
2. I searched the registry keys for this path and found that this path was included in the `*Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1659004503-1897051121-1177238915-282167\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun*` value.
3. Note that this was not under **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** registry directory as mentioned in the comments above.
4. After removing this registry key, everything works now.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, nvm-windows "destroy" my windows setting.
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

I uninstall nvm-windows than go to `AppData` (hidden folder sometimes) - change to visible: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028316/windows-view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-10 and remove `npm` cache manually (Under  `username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`)

Also, run windows command `%temp%` Ctrl + A (select all) and delete - to clean up your system (maybe related).

Some of my global `-g-` packages (Like `vue-cli` should re-install) - after this weird bug (Nightmare).

Comment: run `%temp%` from where?

Comment: Window "run" : http://lexisnexis.custhelp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1084415/~/clearing-the-windows-temp-folders. I am not sure if this issue related.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Running ***npm*** gave me this error:

```
C:\Users\user>npm
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I ended up uninstalling nodejs from the Control Panel and re-installing with a fresh download.

The error doesn't say it couldn't find the command, so I figured it was something wrong with the npm script. The script is located at ***C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd***, found via the path var. ***echo %path%***.

The script contained:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\/bin/sh.exe" (
  "%~dp0\/bin/sh.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*
) ELSE (
  /bin/sh  "%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*
)
```

This looked wrong, as there are forward slashes for Windows and no sh.exe file where the script wants it to be. There is also no /bin/sh file, because its Windows :( Which is why it can't find the specified path.

I tried to get node working in cygwin because its resembles linux and makes Windows at least somewhat bearable. Maybe this was the problem?

Anyway after re-installing the npm.cmd file looks like:

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe" "%~dp0\.\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*
) ELSE (
  node "%~dp0\.\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*
)
```

The slashes look right and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Cygwin or any other Linux emulating shell as your Command Line? If that's the case a possible cause could be a known bug with the npm script. Please try the solution suggested 
here,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22436199/2390020

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with OneDrive on Windows 10 for me. Moving the file outside of OneDrive and onto desktop solved the issue. Kibana was throwing the error for me.