# Npm can't find the path specified

Tags: node.js

```
C:\Users\me>npm
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

(My path is PATH: ...C:\Program Files\nodejs)

It is recognizing npm but there is some sort of configuration issue. What's wrong?

Unlike [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485632/node-js-npm-error-message-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified), my npm.cmd file is not corrupt.

If I use the npm command prompt, everything works; but on the standard command prompt, any npm or node command (eg: node -v or npm -v) gives "The system cannot find the path specified.".

```
node version: 6.2.2
npm version: 3.9.5
```

Comment: Check whether node.js is installed properly or not.

Comment: @arjunkori I'm pretty sure it is - how can I check?

Comment: Go in your PATH variable, check if it points to an existing NodeJS install

Comment: node -v and npm -v. Those will tell you which versions you have installed of each; please post that to aid debugging.

Comment: @RDardelet The only install linked to by PATH is c:\Program Files\nodejs\. This is the only install of node.

Comment: Yeah that's the one it should have, there is no npm path value since it goes through the node.exe app

Comment: did you solve this problem? How ?