# npm - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I have installed `nodejs`. When I try and use `npm` via power shell or cmd it returns

> The system cannot find the path specified.

If I run `node -v` everything works fine. I can use `npm` via the `nodejs` console just fine as well. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling `nodejs` multiple times and it didn't help.

Any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: Do you have the path to nodeJS in your path?

Answer (score 52):

For anyone who runs into this trying to debug this error on why `npm run <script>` doesn't work on Windows for things in node_modules/.bin/ such as gulp, it relates to the fact that npm is using cmd.exe instead of bash for the child.

You can fix this with NPM 5.1.0+ using `npm config set script-shell bash`

Comment: Thanks man, lost a lot of time today to find this! Saved me a lot more time!

Comment: I spend 2 days on this and finaly found your answer. Thank you.

Comment: This can be persisted in your code repo: Create `.npmrc` with contents `script-shell = powershell` (or similar)

Comment: same here spent a lot of time but this got resolved my issue, thank you so much

Comment: I thought because I was using git bash I was in the clear, but still needed your fix.  Thanks.

Comment: For me, I used ```npm config set script-shell powershell```

Comment: Using this (on Windows) resulted in me being unable to install certain npm packages. As @Blaze mentioned, using ```npm config set script-shell powershell``` fixes this issue.

Answer (score 13):

I had exactly the same issue and solved it by following the steps in [npm Troubleshooting](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting) as linked by @royki

1. install the latest globally `npm install -g npm@latest`
2. I applied Options 1. and 2. consecutively in the [npm Troubleshooting Upgrading on Windows](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows)

> - Option 1: [edit your Windows installation's `PATH`](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) to put `%appdata%\npm` before `%ProgramFiles%\nodejs`. Remember that you'll need to restart `cmd.exe` (and potentially restart Windows) when you make changes to `PATH` or how npm is installed.
> - Option 2: remove both of
>
>   - `%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\npm`
>   - `%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\npm.cmd`

Answer (score 8):

I found the problem.
I needed to move my node paths further up the list. Windows must have been looking for NPM in the wrong path variable. 
I moved my node path to the top of the system path variables and now NPM works.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

For me, nothing else worked. The problem was solved by invoking `npm install` after deleting `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Thank YOU!  I ran into this with electron.

Answer (score 3):

For my case, and it's working fine for me:

- I have delete folder **npm folder** in path: C:\Users\ [YOUR USER]\AppData\Roaming\npm
- I have delete folder **npm-cache folder** in path: C:\Users\ [YOUR USER]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

Comment: Thank you for this. Installing/removing node wasn't working. I removed these folders and ran the node installer to remove node. Then restarted PC, installed node again and now it is working again :D +1

Answer (score 3):

This problem arose for me when I installed a new terminal from the Microsoft webstore. When installing that I think I gave it many permissions that I wasn't completely sure of! I mean I was doing what it wanted me to do.

But this action of mine caused the error for me whenever I was starting or running a node server.

> The system cannot find the path specified.

I tried many solutions including reinstalling the node, checking the path in the environment variable, etc. But the thing that worked for me was:

```
npm config set script-shell powershell
```

This script configured powershell as a terminal to be used for npm commands.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed `Node` in Windows. Normally `NODE_PATH` should be automatically added.

For your case check the below SO [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768549/node-js-doesnt-recognize-system-path)

Check also this post for [ENVIRONMENT SET UP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_environment_setup.htm) of NODE for Linux and Windows OS.

**Updated**

1. Troubleshooting [npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting)
2. [npm-windows-upgrade](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade)

Comment: I have node in my path variables. I have the same path variables as my other computer (which npm works fine on btw) Here is an image for npm not working but node working https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_NN3_r3g9pyMV8tVkpmdzZLNmM here is my path variables with nodejs in it https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_NN3_r3g9pyNjY3TWpQWXNuY1E

Comment: Ok I updated the answer. Check those link. Did you try to run from cmd? Does it work from cmd ?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a script that i set to autorun in the windows registry and i had moved the script without changing the path in the registry.

Deleting this key fixed my issue:

```
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1659004503-1897051121-1177238915-282167\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59584302/373207

Answer (score 0):

For me, I simply had a **folder name with a space in the path** and that was treated as a new command.

For context, my `npm start` does this

```
"setup-dev-test-env": "cross-env __fakedirname=%cd% PUBLIC_URL=id-000/fake/path/to/index.html NODE_ENV=development REACT_APP_MOCK_HOSTNAME=localhost REACT_APP_MOCK_PORT=69 REACT_APP_ROOT_QUERY_PARAM=/ro/420/ot.ini",
"start": "npm run setup-dev-test-env react-scripts start"
```

and, since the current folder path (`%cd%`) included a space, it would try and run something that didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:
You probably have an old installation that has not been completely deleted.
Remove NODE and NPM again by following this link: [How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows).
And then install again.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using windows you might need to do this :

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "cd .\\server && npm run start",
    "client": "cd .\\client && npm run start",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\"  \"npm run client\""
  }
```

You need to go to the correct folder path by using `.\\`.