# npm or yarn test fails with "npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT"

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I am trying to follow a tutorial on how to fork Compound (https://medium.com/compound-finance/a-walkthrough-of-contributing-to-the-compound-protocol-9450cbe2133a). I want to add a new token. But in order to do that, I need to first be able to get the app to pass all tests.

The problem is that I can't get the tests to run in the first place. According to the tutorial, I simply need to type `yarn test` to run the tests. However, when I try to do this, I get error messages that seem to imply that it cannot find the path to the test file. For example:

> '.\script\test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> error Command failed with exit code 1.
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command." >

or

> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\tombl\Documents\Code\compound-protocol
> npm ERR! errno -4058
> npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent>

After investigating some, I discovered that it is trying to run a script in package.json called "test".

The script looks like this: `"test": "./script/test",`

At first, I got a response saying that "." is not a recognized command. I then tried to put the entire pathname in it so that it wouldn't have a period in it. So I edited package.json to say `"test": "C:/Users/tombl/Documents/Code/compound-protocol/script/test",`

That didn't work. Next, I tried to edit the environment variables in Windows so that CMD would recognize the folder (I'm using a terminal from within Visual Studio Code). That didn't work either.

After reading some other stack exchange answers, I followed the advice here ([npm - The system cannot find the path specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190164/npm-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified)) and typed `npm config set script-shell bash`. This also didn't work.

In addition, I tried editing package.json so that there is a second set of quotes in the path, like this: `"test": "'C:/Users/tombl/Documents/Code/compound-protocol/script/test'",` But it still didn't work.

Oh, and I tried using `npm test` instead of `yarn test`.

At this point, I have no idea what to try next.

I can see very clearly in file manager that the "test" file is there and that the path I've stated is correct. I can even open up the test file and see the code inside of it. But I can't get the terminal to run it. It just says that it isn't there.

One clue I do have is that it stops at the folder "compound-protocol". So it either doesn't recognize the folder compound-protocol at all or it doesn't recognize that the script folder is inside of it.

I've wondered if maybe the hyphen in "compound-protocol" is causing the problem, but the only advice I've gotten on how to fix that is to put the whole path in quotes, which I've already tried.

I've even tried navigating to the script folder within the terminal and running the test from there. While it does let me navigate into the script folder, trying to run the test produces a > Program 'test' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1. > error message.

Does anyone know how I might go about fixing this?

Comment: The test file seems to be a bash script, but you are on a windows system, which does not come with a bash shell. Do you have wsl installed? Or probably git for windows? You might use the mingw shell that comes with git as default shell for npm

Comment: Thanks @derpirsher. Can you direct me to a tutorial on how to do that? I have Git for Windows. But I'm not sure how to use it to fix this. And I don't know what "wsl" is. Unfortunately, I have only used Truffle for testing in the past.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use `yarn install` first? Also you need to use Node.js version 12 with that repository. NVM is a great tool to quickly switch between versions of Node on the command line. https://nvm.sh