# npm - The system cannot find the path specified (But then shows the result)

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, cmd, npm-install

I am using npm after installing nodejs.
I have installed it once before and I just finished deleting all the components because it kept giving the error in the image below, but when I try to use npm, I keep getting errors saying.

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Even though I reinstalled node, it still gives these weird errors where it says the error twice on powershell and once on cmd.

I'm so confused :(
[image]

Comment: Could be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485632/node-js-npm-error-message-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using nvm to manage your node versions. You can just change your node version and it should work. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the current nvm version by using the command `nvm current`.
If that is not the version which you currently installed or updated, use the command `nvm use <new_version>`
for example: `nvm use 16.17.0`